# Gulp: how to save output in a variable instead of saving it in a file?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I'm using a gulp task to do something for me. However, I don't want to save the output in a file (e.g. gulp.dest('folder/destination/'). I want to save the output, as a string, in a variable. So I want something like this:

```js
// this is how I know to do it
gulp.task('example', function() {
  gulp.src('folder/source/')
  .pipe(uglify()) // this does not need to be uglify() – it can be anything else
  .dest('folder/destination')
  
// this is how I want to do it
var save_it_here
gulp.task('example', function() {
  gulp.src('folder/source/')
  .pipe(uglify()) // this does not need to be uglify() – it can be anything else
  .dest(save_it_here) // this line is where I have problem
```

Comment: What's the goal of you saving it in a variable? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: there is a similar post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36422699/gulp-how-to-get-gulp-result-as-variable